# Static checking of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, static-analysis

One of the great features of PHP was `php -l`, which checked all the code for syntax without executing it.  Is there a similar way to do so for JavaScript in AngularJS? That is, in addition to my test suite coverage (which may not be 100%, and won't be instant if it is), is there a way to (perhaps using Node) check that all of my code compiles properly etc.

Comment: look at Gulp, gulp jshint

Comment: Use CoffeeScript :) It compiles to JSlint-proof javascript code, and the compiler will stop and tell you if there's any syntax errors.

Comment: Don't confuse "syntactically correct"  for "compiles properly",  or syntax-checking for static-analysis.

Answer (score 1):

By using node.js and a build tool called Gulp, you can easily set up and manage an automatic code validation. In fact, you can automate linting, minification and copying of JavaScript files, bundling/concat, renaming, testing, test code coverage etc etc.. List goes on.

How to install and use gulp is [documented on their Github repository](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp), and there is even a sample file to get you started. Smahing Magazine have a [detailed tutorial](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/11/building-with-gulp/) about using Gulp as a build/test tool aswell.

Lint JavaScript files example:

```
// Gulpfile.js
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint');

gulp.task('js-lint', function () {       // Task name
   return gulp.src('js/*.js')            // source files
      .pipe(jshint())                    // library
      .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))  // reporter 
});
```

Comment: You may also want to look at ESLint as an alternative to JSLint. You can find the gulp plugin here: https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint